# How to get the text field and edit text as this format in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-widget

How do I get the style as in [this link](http://www.google.com/imgres?q=facebook+login+page+for+iphone+app&hl=en&biw=1517&bih=741&tbm=isch&tbnid=B3Lzdk9iccTLoM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.zdnet.com/photos/facebook-messenger-for-android/6274957&docid=Yx91nEbZbOk9sM&imgurl=http://i.zdnet.com/gallery/6274960-480-800.jpg&w=480&h=800&ei=U-_HT4iAMoTe0QGY6LzsDw&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=360&sig=108520165499131102780&page=1&tbnh=115&tbnw=70&start=0&ndsp=41&ved=1t:429,r:2,s:0,i:75&tx=54&ty=68)? like the facebook one

Comment: You can create an XML style in your resources folder.  As far as that exact style, that's up to you to figure out, or please show a bit of work on your part.

Comment: Link is broken for me. Try a direct link: http://i.zdnet.com/gallery/6274960-480-800.jpg

Comment: What my doubt is can we set the radius of the field only for two particular side that way I could leave the bottom sides of the first field with 0dp and the top sides of the second field with 0dp....is it possible to set this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<shape>` drawable in XML with only some corners rounded. For example:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <stroke android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" android:width="1dp" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

This only works on API levels 8 and above. Before that there was a bug that causes the 0dp corner radius attributes to be ignored (all corners are rounded). That can be overcome by using a `<layer-list>` drawable with a rounded rectangle and a square rectangle or two layered with it. Depending on what you want the borders to look like, it can be a little tricky to get them right, but a little experimenting should do the trick.